# Is there a way to override the default java class loader to log each class that it loads?

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to override the default java class loader to log each class that it loads?

For example, I'd like my program to output something like: `Loaded class: nameOfClass, it took 10ms` for each class that it loads.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
java -verbose:class
```

when running your application. If you need finer control over class-loading process, read about [Java agents](http://blogs.oracle.com/adventures/entry/the_serializer_a_java_agent).

Comment: I don't have control over running of the JVM, its on a server that I don't control (Google App Engine). That's why I asked if I could do it with a custom classloader.